# Why can't I flag a particular question as off-topic?

Tags: support

This [question about potential harm from an Ethernet port](https://superuser.com/q/1305911/13728) is understandably locked. However, even though it generated a couple of good answers, and I can see a potential link to home networking, I don't see it as on topic.

I attempted to flag it as such but only have the option to flag it for moderator attention.

**Is the lack of an off-topic flag due to the lock, or something else?**

Comment: It is due to the lock. The vote-to-close option is also removed.

Comment: Would it be worth it to flag and state why I feel it is off topic?  I'm happy to risk the rejected flag, but don't want to waste a mod's time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the lock is preventing standard flags. From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/295684):

> A question or answer which is *locked* can no longer accept:
>
> - edits
> - up-votes, down-votes
> - comments, comment up-votes
> - new answers *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*
> - close votes, reopen votes *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*
> - new bounties *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*
> - delete votes, undelete votes.

In an ideal world, there would be a comment lock for situations like this that would only block new comments, but alas, locks currently prevent almost all operations on the post.

If there's something that needs doing to a locked post, moderators will have to do it. Therefore, you can cast a custom flag if you believe action needs to be taken there. Alternatively, you can wait until the question gets unlocked (presumably once the attention dies down) and then cast a recommend-closure flag. Personally, I would be inclined to leave the question open, since it's about hardware used in home setups, but others may disagree.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I should have done a googled instead of just searching the meta questions, apparently I need to go home.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the mod who locked it. There was a few key points I considered.

The quality of the answers was *decent*, but it was attracting an inordinate amount of snarky comments. I didn't particularly want to penalise the people doing the *right* thing - just send a message about the tone of commentary

In *theory* SU's kind of meant for folks of a broad range of skills, and this felt like something someone without a solid grounding in networking might wonder about.

Now if folks had voted to close rather than post comments that were snarky, or commenting on the snarkiness it might be closed rather than locked.

I also totally agree with what Ben said and

> Personally, I would be inclined to leave the question open, since it's about hardware used in home setups, but others may disagree.

Comment: Completely understood the lock, and on the other stacks I participate I too hate to see items that provide benefit to at least part of the community removed.  Keep up the good work.